# Whats the easiest way to send messages to my linux daemon app?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Whats the easiest way to send messages to my linux daemon app? Is it possible that `myapp foo bar` can invoke a callback instead of starting a new process? Whats the standard way to communicate with a daemon? Is my most reasonable choice to stick the PID in `/var/run` and create a named pipe or a socket?

Whats is the standard way apps which run on the command line communicate to its daemon process? I'm assuming its impossible to ask linux to call a callback when I type in `myapp foo bar`?

Comment: You could use Inter-process Communication (or IPC). You could use signals. I personally think 0mq is fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Whats is the standard way apps which run on the command line communicate to its daemon process?

There are a number of ways to do this:

## Dropboxes and Signals

A variety of locations are being used to store "pid files" containing a daemon's process ID number:  `/var/run/<app>/<app>.pid`, `/var/run/<app>.pid` (thanks @Adam Katz for edit), `/run/<app>/<app>.pid`, `/run/<app>.pid`,  (see [Askubuntu: Why has /var/run been migrated to /run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57297/why-has-var-run-been-migrated-to-run)).

When the `pid` of the daemon process is known, a command line program (which is running as a separate process) could communicate with the daemon in these ways:

1. Writing something into a prearranged place.  This could be an ordinary file, a database table, or any convenient spot readable by the server.
2. Sending a signal to the daemon.  The common way to do this locally is with the kill system call, [`int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill).

Old School Example: The server multiplexing daemon [xinetd](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-spunix-inetd/) would reread its configuration file after receiving SIGHUP.

The send-a-signal methodology has been made redundant by the [`inotify` API](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) whereby a process can subscribe to file system events. Using signals is useful when you don't want the daemon to act on *every* file change, since not every change may leave the file in a valid state, as when modifying a system config file.

## FIFO or Pipe

A fifo or pipe is simply a special file that blocks processes reading it until some other process has written to it.  You can make a named pipe/fifo in the file system with [`mkfifo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo).  The only tricky thing about this is that pipes should generally be opened unbuffered, e.g. with `open()` as opposed to `fopen()`. Scripting languages sometimes make a facility for pipe-friendly reading/writing:  `Perl` had a `line-buffered` mode set with `$|=1` that was useful for pipes.

More commonly, you see anonymous pipes all the time on the command line with the `|` symbol separating commands which are executed as separate processes.

## Sockets

What about something newer, like mySQL?  The `mysql` database system consists of a command line client `mysql` and a server `mysqld` and may also serve other clients either on the local machine or over the internet.

mySQL communicates using a `socket`.  The server listens to a socket for connections, and forks new processes giving a socket descriptor to the child for processing.  When the child is done processing, it can exit.

There are UNIX sockets and Internet sockets, with different namespaces.  One guide to programming sockets in C on Linux would be the [sockets chapter of the The GNU C Library manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html#Sockets).

No-wait I/O is an alternative to forking off processes.  This is done in C with the `select()` system call, which allows having a process wait for an event on one or more files, including sockets, or a timeout.  The GNU C Library docs includes [a no-wait I/O socket server example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html#Server-Example)

[NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) is a server for the Javascript language, written as a single-threaded server using no-wait I/O, and shows that these techniques are still relevant in modern systems.

## "Callbacks"

> I'm assuming its impossible to ask linux to call a callback when I type in myapp foo bar?

**Maybe**.  But it might be too much work to be worth the trouble.

When you type `myapp foo bar` into "Linux", that's not Linux, you are typing that into your command shell, which is a program running in its own process separate from everything else.

So, unless the functionality you want is built into the command shell, there is normally no way for that command shell to send messages to your other program without starting a new process.

The default command shell for many (but not all) Linux systems is `/bin/bash`.  To communicate with a daemon that listens to sockets from `bash` we would need a socket opening procedure in `bash`. And, sure enough, it exists!

One can listen to a socket in `bash`.  This is the basis for a daemon:

From: [Simple Socket Server in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739196/simple-socket-server-in-bash) [answer by dtmilano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743398/103081):

> Q: I have a simple debugging solution which writes things to 127.0.0.1:4444 and I'd like to be able to simply bind up a port from bash and print everything that comes across. Is there an easy way to do this?
>
> A:
>
> $ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444
>
> $ cat <&3

One can also open a socket from bash to a remote process, i.e. communicate with a a daemon:

From: [TCP connection, bash only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765004/tcp-connection-bash-only)

we learn `exec 5<>"/dev/tcp/${SERVER}/${PORT}"` redirects a TCP link to file descriptor 5 for both input and output.

Not all `bash` programs are compiled with TCP support.  It is apparently Linux-distribution dependent.  At least according to a comment [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765082/103081) by [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)

There are other shells besides `bash`.  Many shells were developed back in the *nix days. `ksh` Korn shell.  `csh` C-shell. Bourne shell `sh`. Ash shell. Wikipedia keeps a [list of shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells). And these shells each have their own advantages and disadvantages and are not entirely compatible with each other's formatting!

Fast forward about 30 years, and there aren't so many in common use now.

But an important feature exists here: **each user can choose his own login shell**.  See the [`chsh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) command.

So where I am going here is that if `bash` doesn't support the communications you need to do, you could set up a command shell where special messages can be sent without opening a new process.  This might save you a few milliseconds, and usually isn't worth it.  But nothing is stopping you.  You might even set up an ipython command shell, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/209670/103081, and python can import most anything you need to do socket communications with your specialized daemon.

Comment: On Linux (at least Debian, Ubuntu, and RHEL), PIDs are stored as `/var/run/<app>/<app>.pid` or else `/var/run/<app>.pid` rather than at the root of `/var` (I don't have OS X at the ready to compare).

Comment: hah, interesting; I hadn't noticed the symlink.  Thanks for the askubuntu link.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many inferior questions in your post, so they can't all be answered in a single compact response. Also, some questions are  like taste compare request - I mean "what's the best way?" - and this kind of questions is usually disliked at SO. Despite this I'll try to provide at least basic references you can continue with.

> Whats the easiest way to send messages to my linux daemon app?

There is no such way unless you are already using some framework which provide such way. Daemons are too different. Some require only a simple set of fixed messages, some require complex reconfiguration and on-the-fly modification of internal data. The main set of approaches is:

1. Unix signals are really the simplest way to provide protected (with minor simplification, only the same user or the superuser can send them), idempotent (repeat shall not change signal meaning), non-parameterized message; such message set is very limited (~50 freely used ones in Linux). They are delivered asynchronously but can be converted to internal message queue members in a target application. Their main usage is for simple messages as "stop gracefully", "reread your configs" or "turn on debug messages".
2. Unix domain sockets are the basic IPC transport for any interactions (except the most fast ones where shared memory is better). They allow datagrams (like UDP), byte streams (like TCP) and message streams (like SCTP or SPX). A listening socket shall be represented in file system with a path known to clients; Unix file access rights will regulate access to it or you can check credentials explicitly. Virtually any protocol can be built over such sockets, but only clients from the same running OS can connect it, such sockets aren't automatically visible even from host OS in virtualization case.
3. Non-pipe-style IPC: shared memory and semaphores can be used for high load interactions but they require strong usage discipline. There are two versions of such interfaces (SysV and Posix).
4. Internet domain sockets provide the same transports as Unix domain sockets, allow access from any remote client (not nessessarily on the same OS) but don't provide access checks automatically, so client authentication is needed. Also transport protection is often needed (SSL/TLS and so on).
5. Various frameworks are provided over socket interfaces which implement some parts of needed functionality such as registration, endpoint publishing, server search, and so on. For local interactions, this now starts with Dbus which is message-oriented and allows named servers and typed messages either in common OS space or user-local space.
6. Different netwide message transports are developed in last years (AMQP, ZeroMQ, Apache Kafka, etc.) They are designed for using in distributed network, but often without any authentication.

The main issue with self-made daemon is that you shall attach any of these interfaces explicitly and provide a framework to listen for, decode and process incoming messages. If your application has already to be message-driven, you can put it into an environment which is message-driven by design (Erlang, J2EE...), unless you are scared for rewriting to another language :)

> Is it possible that myapp foo bar can invoke a callback instead of starting a new process?

It's more style related question than principal one. You can name a control tool in the same way as a long running one. There are such examples in practice: SysV init (`telinit` is only convenience name), firefox (without -no-remote it tries to connect to already running instance), but generally, separate names are preferred:

- `apachectl` starts/stops/controls daemon but the daemon name is `httpd`;
- `rndc` for `named`, `gdc` for `gated`, etc.

If a daemon binary is a very fat guy, cost to start it each time for a small control message is too high and shall be avoided. But if you really want to do this way, determine two things:

- Do you want it to start automatically unless a running instance is found?
- How will you distingiush daemon starting request from control request?

If you have strong answers to both questions, you needn't worry.

> Whats the standard way to communicate with a daemon?

No, there is no a *single* standard way. There are a few standard ways, see above. One shall choose a way on determined pros and cons.

> Is my most reasonable choice to stick the PID in /var/run and create a named pipe or a socket?

Again, see above, but you'd know that, unless the daemon has root rights, /run (/var/run) isn't writable. A non-root daemon shall use totally another directory (e.g. ~/run/ for its dedicated user home dir) or be provided with a writable subdirectory.

> I'm assuming its impossible to ask linux to call a callback when I type in myapp foo bar?

You again asked for "callback" I don't understand exactly what it stands for. If your daemon is written in an imperative language out of event-driven environment, any message receiving from other processes shall be implemented explicitly. For Unix signals, you write signal receiving functions and configure process to start them on incoming signal. For sockets, you shall create socket, give it a known address, put it into listening mode and provide code to accept incoming connections, gather and decode messages, etc. Only for already event-driven environment, you can use standard methods.

For Erlang, such remote control is very often implemented as connect to daemon node and RPC request using gen_server:call() or analog. The called Erlang process processes this in generic code without any need to implement cases a requester was another process at the same node or from a separate one.

There are some frameworks which have already implemented some of this need in procedural environments; e.g. Dbus client libraries can be written in a way they

- create a separate thread for Dbus socket listening;
- accept incoming messages and call the callbacks you specify,

but this has its own disadvantages:

- a callback is run in its own thread; you shall provide proper synchronization to avoid data spoiling;
- with huge message rate, flow control is at least too rough, or even impossible, and a daemon could be overflowed early before it realises bus connect shall be stopped.

To summarize, your initial question was like "How I could reach my friend's home in an efficient way?" with minimum of details. You can simply step 20 meters if your friend resides next door, or you can ride a bike, or you need to call taxi, or you need to rent a space ship to reach back side of the Moon:) You should repeatedly narrow your requirements until a single variant remains.