# How can I "control" and detach a running program from the console on a Raspberry Pi/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

Given the following C program:

```
int main() {
   do_something();

   if (console_command_m_got) {
      do_something_else_1();
   }
   if (console_command_q_got) {
      exit();
   }


   return 0;
}
```

When I start a C program in the terminal, it runs there. I am looking for a way to start the program from the terminal, but detach it from that terminal. It should not close, when I close the console and run in the background like when I put it in the autostart.

Is there any possibility, to change the control flow of that running program by entering commands in the console? A little example of how I could imagine the workflow:

```
$ ./run_program         // Program starts and runs in background
$ ./run_program -m      // Modify the behaviour of the running program (if-statement above)
$ ./run_program -q      // Stop the running program
```

Or maybe, I have a complete wrong approach.

Comment: Do you mean "How do I [double fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932592/why-fork-twice)?" You do that and write a "PID file" used to control it or have some kind of IPC socket available.

Comment: How often are you expecting to need to tell it to do something different? Every millisecond? Once every few seconds? How many different possible instructions are there likely to be? 2-3? 800? Just trying to get a *"feel"* for the bounds.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636661/force-cli-to-use-existing-process) help at all?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I should only be required to change the behaviour maybe every few minutes in worst case. Possible instructions could be around 5-10.@tadman that sounds nice, I*ll have a look at this!

Comment: A unix socket is pretty nice for forwarding commands to an already-running instance.  Also see `nohup` and/or installing your own SIGHUP handler inside your code.

Comment: The very simplest, IMHO, and also rather inelegant is to create a file called say `EXIT` or `FASTER` in the Terminal with `touch EXIT` and your program checks for that file's existence every time through its main loop and deletes it when seen as acknowledgment. tink's answer provides more sophisticated ideas. YMMV.

Comment: @tadman That worked perfectly for me. Thank you! If you add it as an answer, I will mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out `screen`? It can be scripted as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162150 to run in detached mode and run the called script (which could run your program) in the background. You can then find it again with `screen -ls` and re-attach to the session with `screen -r name-of-screen`.

Comment: `screen` is always useful to know, but this doesn't address the "make the running process do something different when invoked with a parameter", so it's technically not an answer to the question  ...