# Powershell to Bash, Invoke_RestMethod

Tags: bash, powershell

I am pretty new to Bash, so forgive my stupid questions.

The goal is to query an API in Bash, currently i am doing so with PS.

I am trying to convert my Powershell script to Bash, but not getting anywhere.
Example in PS to GET the specific Model_id from a specific asset ($x).

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$API_Key = Get-Content -Path $ScriptDir\API-key.ps1
$bearer_token = "$API_Key"
$header = @{"Authorization" ="Bearer "+$bearer_token}
$url_GET = "https://test-inventory/api/v1/hardware/bytag/$x"
$Asset = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url_GET -Headers $header
$Model_id = $Asset.Model_id
```

Same for making a new asset trough POST

```
$url_POST = 'https://test-inventory/api/v1/hardware'
$Body = @{ "asset_tag" = "123"; "Another_example" = "dunno"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url_POST -Headers $header -Body $Body
```

It is pretty simpel code in PS, but for some reason i can't get my head around it in Bash.

Comment: calling out to [tag:curl] would be one way to do it.

Comment: True! but i want to keep to code as "Linux basic" as possibel, and curl has to be installed. This is partially because the code is meant for large batches of "new" pc's

Comment: It's a fairly safe assumption to say that most Linux systems will have *either* `curl` or `wget` installed. You could check for the `curl` command, if it exists, use it, otherwise check for the `wget` command, if it exists, use it.

Comment: Well, you *can* make a raw TCP connection in plain bash (https://stackoverflow.com/q/7765004/7552), but really why would you want to go back to (basically) telnetting in to the web server?

Comment: @glennjackman thats more the kind of thing i am looking for, thanks man! Its a special kind of usecase i admit :P